# how to show hidden div from codebehind c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I'm trying to initialize a usercontrol that contains a gridview as hidden when a page first loads. When the user clicks a "Search" button on the page then I want to show the gridview that's within that usercontrol. I've tried a bunch of different methods for showing and hiding the user control. I've tried placing the usercontrol in a div and then using style="display: none" to initialize the div as being hidden, and then in the code behind changing the style to 'block'. I've tried using 2 classes with one class having display set to none and the other with display set to block, and then switching between these 2 classes based on user clicking on "Search" button. I've tried using a Panel and setting its visibility to true/false, but the panel never shows when I set its visibility to true after the user clicks on the Search button. All methods I've tried, except using a panel and its visibility option, give me the following exception:

```
{InnerText = '((System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl)(divGrid)).InnerText' threw an exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException'}
```

Here's the code I'm using that's causing me this error:

markup:

```
<div id="divGrid" runat="server">
    <uc1:ContactsGridUserControl ID="ContactsGridUserControl1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional"/>      
</div> 

<asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" Font-Size="Small" Height="30px" 
                Width="67px" ClientIDMode="Static" onclick="btnSearch_Click"></asp:Button>
```

code behind:

```
protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //string redirect = CommonStrings.editContactPage;
    bool bStatus = false;

    try
    {
        bStatus = validateFields();

        if (bStatus)
        {
            divGrid.Style["display"] = "block";           

        }
        else
        {
            lblError.Text = "Please enter characters for at least one field below";

        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        lblError.Text = "Exception: " + ex.ToString();
    }
}

protected bool validateFields()
{
    try
    {
        if ((txtbxFirstName.Text != null && txtbxFirstName.Text.Length > 0) ||
            (txtbxLastName.Text != null && txtbxLastName.Text.Length > 0) ||
            (txtbxPhoneNum.Text != null && txtbxPhoneNum.Text.Length > 0) ||
            (txtbxCity.Text != null && txtbxCity.Text.Length > 0) ||
            (txtbxZipCode.Text != null && txtbxZipCode.Text.Length > 0) ||
            (txtDate1.Text != null && txtDate1.Text.Length > 0) ||
            (txtDate2.Text != null && txtDate2.Text.Length > 0) ||
            (txtbxCompanyName.Text != null && txtbxCompanyName.Text.Length > 0))
        {
            return true;

        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        lblError.Text = "Exception: " + ex.ToString();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Full Stack Trace: (I right clicked on Call Stack Window within Visual Studio and chose "show external code". I'm not sure if I did this right to show full stack trace, as opposed to showing what's on top of the stack by default)

> App_Web_gjla55xr.dll!AdvancedSearch.btnSearch_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e) Line 50  C#
>       System.Web.dll!System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(System.EventArgs e) + 0x77 bytes
>       System.Web.dll!System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(string eventArgument) + 0x71 bytes
>       System.Web.dll!System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(string eventArgument) + 0xb bytes
>       System.Web.dll!System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, string eventArgument) + 0xe bytes
>       System.Web.dll!System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection postData) + 0x25 bytes
>       System.Web.dll!System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(bool includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, bool includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) + 0x15bc bytes
>       System.Web.dll!System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(bool includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, bool includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) + 0x8d bytes
>       System.Web.dll!System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest() + 0x4f bytes 
>       System.Web.dll!System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(System.Web.HttpContext context) + 0x16 bytes
>       System.Web.dll!System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(System.Web.HttpContext context) + 0x32 bytes
>       App_Web_gjla55xr.dll!ASP.advancedsearch_aspx.ProcessRequest(System.Web.HttpContext context) + 0x33 bytes    C#
>       System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() + 0x65 bytes 
>       System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep step, ref bool completedSynchronously) + 0x4c bytes 
>       System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.ApplicationStepManager.ResumeSteps(System.Exception error) + 0x13e bytes
>       System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(System.Web.HttpContext context, System.AsyncCallback cb, object extraData) + 0xf8 bytes
>       System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestInternal(System.Web.HttpWorkerRequest wr) + 0x1a2 bytes 
>       System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNoDemand(System.Web.HttpWorkerRequest wr) + 0x7d bytes
>       System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequest(System.Web.HttpWorkerRequest wr) + 0x47 bytes
>       WebDev.WebHost40.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.WebHost.Request.Process() + 0x17b bytes 
>       WebDev.WebHost40.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.WebHost.Host.ProcessRequest(Microsoft.VisualStudio.WebHost.Connection conn) + 0x6c bytes
>       [Appdomain Transition]
>       WebDev.WebHost40.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.WebHost.Server.OnSocketAccept(object acceptedSocket) + 0x83 bytes
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(object state) + 0x2d bytes 
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool ignoreSyncCtx) + 0xb0 bytes
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem() + 0x5a bytes 
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch() + 0x147 bytes
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback() + 0x2d bytes
>       [Native to Managed Transition]

Edit: I solved the answer to my problem. I needed to surround the user control with an ajax update panel and have a asyncpostbacktrigger wired to the Search button click event. I also surround the usercontrol with another panel and set that panel's visibility to true/false from code behind.

updated code:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlGrid" Visible="false" runat="server">   
            <uc1:ContactsGridUserControl ID="ContactsGridUserControl1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional"/>
        </asp:Panel>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSearch" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
```

Comment: Your `div` has a class `hidden`... perhaps you should remove that class instead?

Comment: Any inner exception? Show the stack!

Comment: Hey Jeff, I removed the class hidden. Sorry about that confusion, that was code left over from another method I tried when I was swapping 2 different classes, one class with display set to none and the other classes with display set to block. After taking out class=hidden I still get the same error

Comment: Hey Charleh, how do I show the stack? I see a call stack window, but that only shows what's currently on top of the stack. I'm using Visual Studio 2010. Thanks!

Comment: Can you debug into `validateFields()`? I guess the actual exception is thrown in there. And check the InnerException, if there is any.

Comment: I debugged into validateFields() and didn't see an exception. I've posted the code to validateFields() above so you can see it if you like. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the base class for all ASP.NET WebForms controls is HtmlControl which has a **[Visible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.ui.control.visible%28v=vs.80%29)** property.  Would this work?:

```
divGrid.Visible = true;
```

Comment: I tried that but for some reason the div doesn't show. I tried using a panel as well and trying to set visible to true, and that still didn't work

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the answer to my question. I had to surround the user control with an update panel and set the trigger to a click event of the Search button. I also surrounded the usercontrol with a panel and simply set visible to true/false.

Answer (score 1):

I actually encounter this problem. I used `divControl.Visible = false;` on Page_Load event, it was solved buy mystically that code distrupts my page format. So at last resort i tried  `divControl.Style.Add("visibility", "hidden");` on Page_Load event
 `divControl.Style.Add("visibility", "visible");` on a desired method it is solved and not distrupt page format.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember right I had a similar problem a while back and it was due to processing at some point not working if the control was not visible at page load (or some point at startup). I don't quite remember the details right now.

Ideas to work around:

- use jquery to hide it at document ready
- make the position of the element off screen when "hidden" and move it back to where it goes when you want to display it

If none of that works please post the full stack trace.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far! I tried those suggestions, and unfortunately they would hide the div but not show it. I posted the full stack trace above. Thanks!

Comment: You might double check that the codebehind isn't setting the control to be not visible in some way.