# displaying a div tag from code behind

Tags: c#, html, code-behind

I am trying to display a div tag from code behind but what I have tried does not seem to work.

On page Load I do the following(to hide the div) which seems fine.

```
loginLoader.Attributes.Add("style", "display:none");
```

but I cant seem to display it again(in this case on button click)

```
protected void butSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            loginLoader.Attributes.Add("style", "display:block");
            //etc.
```

Advice perhaps the div is not displaying?

regards

Comment: "Possible Duplicate " : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297165/how-to-hide-a-div-from-code-c and 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11162567/how-to-show-hidden-div-from-codebehind-c-sharp

Comment: Is your code to hide the div, inside an `if (!IsPostBack) { ... }` block?

Comment: Yes, this is fine, however, inside a try...catch block is where it doent want to hide or show

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [Style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a9d6h4f%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) instead of Attribute

```
Button1.Style.Add("display", "block");
```

OR

```
Button1.Style["display"] = "block";
```

You think using `visible` property instred of style is more appropriate here.

```
loginLoader.Visible = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

Is your "loginLoader" added to page.controls?
Try add 'LoginLoader' to some another control (for example: page.controls.add(loginLoader) and then find your text in page somewhere by ctrl+F)

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Panel myDiv = new Panel(); //creating dynamic control
            myDiv.Attributes.Add("style", "display:block; width:100px; height:100px; background-color:red;"); //set attrs for visibility
            this.Page.Controls.Add(myDiv); // add to some control (now is Page)
        }
```